# Possible to live the data from rosbag

Tags: ros, rosbag, stream

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to live the data from rosbag and display on graph with respect to time. I googled it ,but not get any solution. I know reading data and writting data into rosbag . I want to display graph when rosbag play command was executed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266918/possible-to-live-the-data-from-rosbag/) by [Obedulla](https://answers.ros.org/users/31284/obedulla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I  see 3 way to display rosbag data in streaming :

---

1. with [rqt_bag](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_bag)

You can use the executable "rqt_bag" (or "rosrun rqt_bag rqt_bag") to open a rqt GUI where you can load a rosbag -> right click on a topic -> view -> plot -> check the data you want on the graph on the new [rqt_plot](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot) GUI and click play.

You will see a graph of your data with a red bar (the timeline) to see the current data. It's not a live streaming (all data appear on the graph) but it's the easiest method.

---

2. with [rqt_plot](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot)

You can play a bag file and open a rqt_plot at the same time with 3 terminal.

On terminal 1, launch a roscore (command "roscore")

On terminal 2, launch play your bag file (command "rosbag play bagname")

On terminal 3, launch rqt_plot (command "rqt_plot" or "rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot")

On the rqt_plot GUI, type the topic you want to display and adjust the axes.

You can also use [PlotJuggler](https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler)

---

3. with [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch)

You can use the previous method but instead of launching "rqt_plot", just launch rqt (with "rqt" or "rosrun rqt rqt")

Then go to plugin > visualization > Plot

Choose the topic you want.

Click on perspective > Export... and save the perspective file where you want (an easy path if possible).

Then you need a roslaunch file that look like this :

```
 <launch>
  <node name="<name_of_your_rosbag_node>" pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" args="play <name_of_your_rosbag>"/>
  <node name="<name_of_your_gui_node>" pkg="rqt" type="rqt" args="--perspective-file <your_perspective_file>"/>
</launch>
```

Then execute your launch file with "roslaunch name_of_your_launch_file".

Your data in live streaming with rqt_plot should open.

---

Originally posted by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) with karma: 591 on 2017-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0